# Using PDF Reactor as Web Service

Tags: reactor, pdf-reactor

I am discovering PDF reactor and I'd like to use it as a web service. To test a file, I use cURL

```
curl -v -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/xml" http://localhost:9423/service/rest/convert/async -d @test.html
```

Is that correct ?

test.html :

```
<html>
<body>
Coucou, je suis terrien.
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help,

Cédrik

**edit #1:**
response from the comman above :

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 9423 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9423 (#0)
> POST /service/rest/convert/async HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.14.3.0 zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: localhost:9423
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/xml
> Content-Length: 50
> 
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Date: Tue, 15 Dec 2015 11:47:29 GMT
< Content-Length: 307
< Server: Jetty(9.3.2.v20150730)
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
JAXBException occurred : élément inattendu (URI : "", local : "html"). Les éléments attendus sont <{http://webservice.pdfreactor.realobjects.com/}configuration>. élément inattendu (URI : "", local : "html"). Les éléments attendus sont <{http://webservice.pdfreactor.realobjects.com/}configuration>.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using the REST API of PDFreactor via cURL you have to send a configuration XML or JSON to the server which includes configuration for PDFreactor and your document, as described here: http://www.pdfreactor.com/product/doc_html/index.html#d0e688

A sample configuration for XML could look like this:

config.xml:

```
<tns:configuration xmlns:tns="http://webservice.pdfreactor.realobjects.com/">
    <document>&lt;html&gt; &lt;body&gt; Coucou, je suis terrien. &lt;/body&gt; &lt;/html&gt;</document>
</tns:configuration>
```

You can then call the following:

```
curl -v -X POST --header "Content-Type:application/xml" http://localhost:9423/service/rest/convert/async.xml -d @config.xml
```

The output will look like the following:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 9423
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 9423
> POST /service/rest/convert/async.xml HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.15.5 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.15.5 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
> Host: localhost:9423
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type:application/xml
> Content-Length: 195
> 
> <tns:configuration xmlns:tns="http://webservice.pdfreactor.realobjects.com/">   <document>&lt;html&gt;&lt;body&gt;Coucou, je suis terrien.&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</document></tns:configuration>HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Accept, Content-Length, content-type, Host, User-Agent
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, PUT, POST, DELETE
< Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Location
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Date: Wed, 16 Dec 2015 16:34:19 GMT
< Location: http://localhost:9423/service/rest/progress/c2a58dbd-ef9d-4b79-87d9-079c139fe9ed
< Content-Length: 0
< Server: Jetty(9.3.2.v20150730)
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

The "Location" response header contains the URL which can be used to retrieve the progress of the conversion, so you can retrieve the progress with (the ID will of course vary):

```
curl -v http://localhost:9423/service/rest/progress/c2a58dbd-ef9d-4b79-87d9-079c139fe9ed
```

This will return the conversion progress and if the conversion has finished the "Location" repsonse header will contain a new URL to retrieve the document. You can use ".pdf" to retrieve the PDF binary data or ".xml" to retrieve XML data containing the PDF as base64 encoded String, the number of pages of the document, etc.

```
curl -v http://localhost:9423/service/rest/document/c2a58dbd-ef9d-4b79-87d9-079c139fe9ed.pdf
```